# Check status of last build in openshift using untilEach openshift jenkins client plugin

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, openshift, jenkins-groovy

I want to check the latest build status using the openshift jenkins client plugin. Following the official documentation [here](https://github.com/openshift/jenkins-client-plugin)

```
stage('Start build') {
  steps {
    script {
      openshift.withCluster() {
        openshift.withProject('my-project') {
          openshift.selector("bc", "app_name").startBuild()
        }
      }
    }
    script {
      openshift.withCluster() {
        openshift.withProject('my-project') {
          def builds = openshift.selector("bc", "app_name").related('builds')
          timeout(5) {
            builds.untilEach(1) {
              return (it.object().status.phase == "Complete")
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above code starts a new build and then checks for all related `builds`' status to the `build config`. I want it to check the status of the build that was started.

It checks for all the previous related builds' status to be `Complete` too. Let's take the below example:

Previous old builds

Build #1 - Complete

Build #2 - Failed

Build #3 - Complete

Build #4 - Complete

When I execute the pipeline in Jenkins - A new `Build #5` gets started and I want the above code to only check for the status of `Build #5` to be `Complete`. But this code checks for all the builds (Build #1 to Build #5) to be in the `Complete` status. Because of that, the pipeline waits until all 5 builds are `Complete` and eventually times out and jenkins build fails.

I only want it to check the status of the latest (last) build. The documentation doesn't have an example of that, but it should be possible. I can vaguely understand it must be possible by using `watch` but not sure how to execute it.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much research turns out the answer was right there in front of my face. Just add the `"--wait"` argument in the previous `startBuild` step.

```
openshift.selector("bc", "app_name").startBuild("--wait")
```

This will return a non-zero code if the build fails and the `stage` will also fail.

Comment: Could you post full solutuin please

Comment: @Akvel Sorry, I don't have the full solution atm. Can you tell me what you are looking for and I'll see if I can assist.